# How many unique patterns can a $4\times 4$ grid make?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a grid of $4\times 4$ size and has values starting from $0$ to $15$. How many unique $4\times 4$ patterns can this grid make?  I have no idea which formula or mathematical concept is required here.

I found it on the internet that told if you take $16!$ (factorial) this is how many unique patterns you. can have with a 4x4 grid. and $16!$ is in trillions? Is this the right way or is there anything else?

**UPDATE:**

> What qualifies as a unique pattern?

Lets say we have $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$ values in our $4\times 4$ grid.

Some unique pattern would be:

- $1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$
- $2,1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$

and so on. The key is that every unique pattern. will have the same values $0-15$ but will be randomized. So how many unique random patterns of $4\times 4$ can we make?

Comment: What counts as a unique pattern? If rotations/symmetries are not counted, then there are $16$ possible choices of numbers for the first box, $15$ for the second, $14$ for the third... $1$ for the last one, which gives a total of $16!$ patterns.

Comment: @player3236 just updated this in my question.

Comment: $16!$ is correct. If you're having trouble following player3236's explanation, try working out a smaller example (e.g. a 2x2 grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$16!$ is correct. It's easy to see from where it comes from.

The first square could contain any of the 16 integers from $0$ to $15$. So, you have $16$ possibilities.

The second square could contain any of the 15 remaining integers. So the number of combinations for 2 squares and 16 integers is $16 \times 15$.

For the i-th square, the number of combinations would be $16 \times 15 \times \cdots \times [16-(i-1)]$.

Think about it with 2 squares and 3 integers $(0,1,2)$, for example.

First square: $(0)$,$(1)$,$(2) \rightarrow 3 \text{ combinations}$.

Second square:  For each integer we can pick any of the other 2 integers remaining. $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,2)$, $(2,0)$ and $(2,1)$. Clearly 3 pairs. $3\times2$

If you considered a third square, there would be only one option for each previous combination, so the number of combinations keeps the same. $3\times2\times1$

Answer (score 2):

$!16$ is correct, you start with the first value having 16 possibilities here, for the 2nd value you have then only 15 possibilities and so on.